# returning data in json format not properly showing

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to return data in sample probvided as in highcarts i tried alot but my data output is quite diferent then showing wihtin highcart when i try to pu my data the graph data is not showing up

can anyone help me out

here is sample data showing from high chart

```
?([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,6),0.7549],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,7),0.7562],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,9),0.7574],
```

This is follwoing out put of my return data

```
["[Date.UTC(2012,05,18), 14.38],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,21), 14.15],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,22), 15.11],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,23), 14.96],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,24), 14.98],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,25), 15.05],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,28), 14.8],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,29), 14.71],
","
[Date.UTC(2012,05,30), 14.72],",
```

Here is my code

```
         $chartData = array();
         foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $date = explode('-', $value['date']);
            $new_date = $date[0]. "," .$date[1]. "," .$date[2];
            $value = $value['closing_rate'];
            $datetime = 'Date.'. 'UTC('.$new_date.')';
            $chartData[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
        }
        echo json_encode($chartData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: try this $chartData[] = array( $datetime, $value);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample data you display in the first block contains Javascript code; `Date.UTC()` is a call of a method `UTC` of the Javascript `Date` class. A JSON cannot contain code, it contains only data.

In the second listing you generate some strings that contain Javascript code. The JSON is properly decoded in Javascript but all it contains is a list of strings that look like the code in the first listing. You don't need the code but its results.

[`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) is a static method of the Javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class that [computes and returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC#Return_value):

> **Return value**
>
> A number representing the number of milliseconds in the given Date object since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00`, universal time.

There are many ways to generate the same value in PHP. The easiest one is to let the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class do the heavy lifting:

```
// Use the UTC timezone
$tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
// Prepare the data here
$chartData = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $date = new DateTime($value['date'], $tz);
    // DateTime::format('U') returns the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970
    // multiply by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds
    $chartData[] = array(1000 * $date->format('U'), $value['closing_rate']);
}


echo json_encode($chartData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

---

**Remark**

If you are running the code on PHP 7 or newer then you can use [`DateTime::format('v')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the number of milliseconds:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $date = new DateTime($value['date'], $tz);
    $chartData[] = array($date->format('v'), $value['closing_rate']);
}
```

Comment: you know what you totally rocks thumbs up for you but there are 2 question if you do not mind me asking 1) the date is showing as 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 not as march 1 2015 march 2 2015 is it because i am showing data for all 5 years ? 2) there are 4 values name1 : value name 2 then value : how can i change that ?

Comment: I did a correction on the code, the second value to put in each array in `$chartData` is `$value['closing_rate']` (it was `$value` before and it was not correct).

Comment: *"the date is showing as 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 not as march 1 2015 march 2 2015 "* -- I guess you are talking about what you see in the browser. First of all you should check (in the browser's Developers Tools) that you get the correct values from the backend. Then, if they are correct, I guess you can configure the charting JS library to use one format or another for the dates it displays. Check its documentation.